# Curl working on SSH but C# web request gives 404 error

Tags: c#, curl, ssh, soap, httpwebrequest

I am trying SOAP request from a Linux SSH. When I use the CURL command, I can get expected SOAP result.

`curl --location 'https://DOMAIN_URI' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' --data 'SOAP body here'`

When I prepared C# web request and deployed in docker. It gives 404 error.

Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```
     try
        {
            
            // Create the web request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https url");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";

            // Set the SOAP envelope as the request body
            string soapEnvelope = @"soap body here";
            byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapEnvelope);
            request.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
            }

            string responseText = "";
            // Make the request and get the response
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                }
            }
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new
            {
                data = new
                {
                    message = responseText,
                    url = _url
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new
            {
                data = new
                {
                    message = ex.ToString(),
                    url = _url
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: And if you run that code outside of docker it works as well?

Comment: @rene, I don't have local access. SOAP request can be called from Linux server. I create docker image and run using SSH. However, CURL command works in the same Linux SSH. I am using .NET 7.0, and I don't think that the docker is an issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Check the URL you're using.

Comment: I have rechecked and URL in curl command and web request are same.

Answer (score 0):

It is because no network in between host and docker container. I have resolved by including the --add-host flag to add a single host to IP mapping within a Docker container. This works for me!

example: --network {network name} --add-host [www.abc.net:xx.xxx.xxx.xx](http://www.abc.net:xx.xxx.xxx.xx)